# How to get Baite Pro Mini working?

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, linux

I have recklessly bought the [Baite Pro Mini](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1432585134.html) and I find it difficult to upload any program. I use Ubuntu Linux, but out of frustration I am ready to install Windows, if it is necessary.

I've read the information from the blog http://nerdralph.blogspot.ca/2014/01/baite-pro-mini-review.html . Too bad, that the blog owner didn't put much details. Can anyone here fill some blanks for me?

1. How exactly should I connect the Arduino device to the computer?
   I have a converter USB to serial pl2303HX: [image: PL2303HX] which I tried to connect with the Baite Pro Mini in almost any plausible permutation of the wires, but never got any result.

---

edit:

Here is the description of pins of the pl2303HX: [image: Pin layout of PL2303HX device]
<sub>(source: [fasttechcdn.com](https://img.fasttechcdn.com/123/1230400/1230400-3.jpg))</sub>

I did connect it the following way:

```
Baite Pro Mini      pl2303HX
GND  
GND  <------------> GND
VCC  <------------> +5V
RXI  <------------> TXD
TXC  <------------> RXD
DTR
```

I also tried the permutation with different `GND` pin. I also tried pressing the `reset` button on the Baite Pro Mini around the time of hitting the "Upload" button on the Arduino standard compiler.

I believe my failure might have something to do with the absence of `DTR` pin on the converter that resets the board just before upload. Are my worries justified? Is there anything I can do?

2. Which exactly [Arduino bootloader](https://docs.arduino.cc/hacking/software/Bootloader) do I need?
3. How to connect USBASP to the Beite Pro Mini?

Comment: GND to GND, VCC to VCC, TX to RX and vice versa.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That was my second try (not first... ;-) ) and it didn't work. I believe my failure might have something to do with the absence of `DTR` pin on the converter that resets the board just before upload. Are my worries justified? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've updated the question

Answer (score 2):

I have several clone Pro Minis I got from several sources on ebay for ~ £2 ($3) each. I also use Ubuntu (10.04 on this old PC but it's fine).

I started with a USB converter similar to yours and it was a bit hit-and-miss choosing when to press the reset to upload. Once I got connections right and worked out when to press reset it became a more reliable procedure but still a pain.

I realised that it would be better to use the auto-reset from DTR so I got a cheapo USB to serial from ebay which claimed to be FTDI (or compatible?) though I didn't know what that meant at the time. With a small converter board to make the right connections it works well.

Your connections look good so if you haven't damaged anything it's probably a matter of when to press reset. Windows won't help!

You must choose the correct board in the Tools menu of the Arduino IDE - Pro Mini with correct AVR chip, speed and voltage. I use programmer AVR ISP (I think)

Comment: His connections look bad - gnd & Vcc are adjacent on the processor board and separated by 2 pins on his converter. 
A reset does not seem to be needed when using the Baite processor AND Baite USB module.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I didn't mean with my diagram to show the actual layout of the *cables*, only the labels on one side and (in random order) the labels on the side of the controller and which pin was connected where.

Comment: I am waiting for a delivery of the USB converter that supports the reset (has a `DTR` pin). I hope it will solve my problems. The chip itself doesn't seem to be broken; when powered the blue diode is blinking exactly the same as it was the first day.

Answer (score 2):

Your connections are incorrect if you are "straight through" connecting.
Gnd & Vcc are adjacent on the processor board and separated by 2 pins on your converter.

If you find Gnd, Vcc, TX, RX on USB module and processor then you should

- Connect Gnd to Gnd
- Connect Vcc to Vcc
- Connect ........TXD to RXD and
   ........................RXD to TXD
- Ensure that you have the correct USB converter drivers loaded.

A reset does not seem to be needed when using the Baite processor AND Baite USB module.

---

I have a number of Baite Pro Minis working perfectly.
In my experience (3 or 4 sales so far) Baite's products are usually of acceptable quality .

Connecting "almost any plausible permutation of the wires" is a fine way to attempt to destroy the converter and/or the BPM. Logical connection should work - if you have not damaged something.

Connect as Ignacio says.
Note that you connect **BPM-TX to USB-converter-RX**, and RX to TX and **NOT RX to RX). The BPM has connections shown on the PCB.

[image]

Baite provide this diagram

[image]

Your converter module has a different pinout which needs to be allowed for.

[image]

You must also have drivers on your system for the USB to serial bridge IC used on your converter. The Baite converter uses a CH340G IC. Your may or may not.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful answer. Don't pay attention to the layout of the pins on the right side, I don't use the "straight through" connection. Pay attention only to the labels. It is cumbersome to draw crossed lines in ASCII.